# How to fix the problem cv2.imshow() on Jupyter? Kernel died

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am tried, but unfortunately can't fix it.

img = cv2.imread("labka.jpg")

cv2.imshow("Over the Clouds", img)

[What shows me terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOYc7.jpg)

Comment: Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My guess is that `imread()` failed to load the input image: `if (img is None): return`

Comment: If everything is fine, the image correctly loaded and all. Please call this after the imshow() line - > cv2.waitKey(0)